# If $M,N$ are $R$-modules and $f:Μ\rightarrow N$ , $g:N\rightarrow M$ are $R$-module homomorphisms s.t. $g\circ f=1_M$ Prove: $N=Im(f)\oplus \ker(g)$

Tags: modules

**Question:** If $M,N$ are $R$-modules and $f:Μ\rightarrow N$ , $g:N\rightarrow M$ are $R$-module homomorphisms s.t. $g\circ f=1_M$

Prove: $N=Im(f)\oplus \ker(g)$

**My attempt:** Since $\forall n\in Im(f)$ we get $g(n)=1_M\neq 0_M$
$\implies Im(f)\cap \ker(g)=\emptyset$

In addition $Im(f)\subseteq N$ and $\ker(g)\subseteq N \implies Im(f)\oplus \ker(g)\subseteq Ν $

However i am having trouble proving that $N\subseteq Im(f)\oplus \ker(g)$

How should i proceed?

Comment: Note that $1_M$ here denotes the *identity function* on $M$, defined as $1_M(m)=m$ and we don't have such an element as $1_M$ in a general module.

Comment: Oh i see now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

I guess that $1_M$ means the identity function on $M$. If $n\in N$, then $$n=\underbrace{n-f\big(g(n)\big)}_{\in \ker(g)}+\underbrace{f\big(g(n)\big)}_{\in \text{Im(f)}}.$$